# Pick the right tag: merge [datapicker] with [datepicker]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

I recently stumbled on the [datapicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datapicker) tag. As far as I know, no such thing as a datapicker exists, and all of the questions I could find were either about datepickers, or vague.

Since it has 92 questions, it's probably a really common spelling error.

Please merge the datapicker tag with [datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datepicker) (obviously keeping the correctly spelled one), and add a synonym to help people who misspell this tag

Comment: Y'all can vote for the synonym [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datepicker/synonyms)

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think the datapicker tag needs to exist at all. It seems to be a typo that has been repeatedly picked up on nearly 100 questions where they should instead just be using datepicker.